# How to run a command on a linked docker container?

Tags: python, ruby, docker, command-line, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose with:

1. an existing (python) app running inside a docker container.
2. another (ruby) command-line app running in a docker container.

How do I 'connect' those two containers so that the python container can call the command-line app in the ruby container? (and pass arguments via stdin/stdout)

Comment: Maybe you could make a volume to share the Ruby command-line app and mount this volume in the Python container

Comment: I can share a volume, but how do I run the command inside the *other* container?

Comment: @gingerlime, are the two container running currently and you want to run the a command in one of the container?

Comment: maybe something like `docker exec <container> <command>`. or `docker exec -it <container> <command>` if you want to get the terminal from the container to see what happens

Comment: @Rao the python container is running, and it needs to some times call a command on the ruby container. Tryph - this works outside both of the container. I want to run the command from *inside* the containers.

Comment: Was it a periodic job to be executed from inside the container? `cronjob` helps? And like @Tryph mentioned, you do not have to login into container and run command.

Comment: It's not a periodic job. It's on-demand. Example: python web app receives a request, and needs to execute a ruby command and return the result.

Comment: I'm not sure about what are you trying, but is SSH an option? If they are linked you can configure a connection between them.

Comment: You should update your question with details from the comments and add any other important detail. Potential answers will be better.

Answer (score 2):

Options are available, but not great. If you're using a recent version of Docker Compose then both containers will be in the same Docker network and can communicate, so you could install `sshd` in the destination container and make `ssh` calls from the source container.

Alternatively, use [Docker in Docker](https://github.com/jpetazzo/dind) with the source container, so you can run `docker exec` **inside** the source and execute commands on the target container.

It's low-level communication though, and raising it to a service call or message passing would be better, if changing your apps is feasible.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid SSH, since it's considered bad practice AFAIK. I'll take a look at Docker-in-Docker, but I'm using a pre-built image so not sure how to 'convert' it to use DiD ... Indeed not great. With all the talks about best-practice of running only one thing in a container, I would have thought this kind of use-case will be somehow straight-forward...